# Why is my Android application crashing on Samsung Galaxy Note 9?

Tags: android, crash, samsung-galaxy

So , I was developing an Android application for Arduino and I was right about to post it on Google Play but first I though I should test it on different devices. So I sent my apk to a few of my friends.

Here are the devices i tested it :

1. One plus 6T : works perfectly
2. Asus zenfone 5z : again works perfectly
3. Samsung galaxy note 9 : when the app is opened it instantly crashes

Has anybody ever encountered such thing ?

My first guess was about the resolution of the device: the first two devices are running at a resolution of about 2280x1080 while the Note 9 runs at 2960x1440.
I added into the Android Manifest file the lines for supporting screens but seems that they don't help.

I also created "Landscape variations" and "tablet variation" for my first three activities but that also didn't helped.

Here is my Manifest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.edi.bluetoothgoogleplay">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
   
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true">

    </supports-screens>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/newicon"
        android:label="Arduino Controller"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_car"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TerminalBluetooth"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't mention what the error is. Have you tried debugging live on the Samsung? If you debug on USB it will hopefully highlight the issue.

Comment: What is the debug message?